# running pskill.exe "access denied"

Tags: process, c#-4.0, kill, access-denied

Im attempting to kill a process remotely by using pskill.

From the command line, pskill works great, but when trying the same command in C# Im getting an access denied error.

```
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                                            FileName = "pskill.exe",
                                            Arguments = "-t \\" + _currentMachine + 
                                                        " -u BobSmith -p Pass123 " + _currentService + 
                                                        " /acceptEULA"
                                         };

    try {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)) {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot forcibly kill process.");
    }
```

I have even tried creating a .bat file which runs fine manually but I get the same error when trying to call the .bat from C#.

Im on an XP machine attempting to access a win 2003 server.

Comment: Does the `BobSmith` account have enough privileges to kill processes?

Comment: Yes, if I manually run the .bat file the process is killed.

Answer (score 1):

For the next guy...

pskill.exe needed to be run in Win2000 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check your credentials.  It is either that or your process is 'locked'.

Comment: Assuming you are right, would you know why running the .bat file manually kills the process but not if I launch the file from within the C# code.

Comment: Looking at it again, how are you getting your _CurrentService.  Have you tried getting PID instead?

Comment: not yet but thats a great suggestion, Ill have to try that next.

Comment: I've always had better luck killing processes by the PID.

Answer (score 0):

In C# characters in strings are escaped by default. The string you assign to Arguments contains two escape characters. I suspect that they are turned into a single back slash. Add an `@` in front of the string definition to resolve this.

```
  Arguments = @"-t \\" + _currentMachine +
```

In any case I would suggest adding code to write the whole command line out to a text file and check that it is as you need it. If the text file has a bat extension can you run it successfully?